# show multiple cardview one above another in android layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to design my application where I want to put multiple Card-view which are revolving . and on vertical slide it will open the card content in fragment above Card view .
I want the design something like below [image Card view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0fVX.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0fVX.png)

Comment: is it something like tinder app layout design?

Comment: no. i want to implement stackview with card so that i can drag the card to any other layout and below it showing list of card in stckview which are scroll vertical to bring backone front and if we dag the front card to another layout it will open there

Answer (score 0):

Try something like Stack View. Check here for example 
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/stackview/android-stackview-example/